# Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in hostinger

Tags: php, hosting, permission-denied

I was trying to create directories automatically with php, with the mkdir() function.

```
<?php
session_start();

$domain = $_SESSION['domain'];
$mydomain = "/" . $domain;
echo $_SESSION['domain'] . " " . $mydomain . "<br />";
$mk = mkdir($mydomain, 0777, true);
if ($mk){
    echo "directory created";
}else{
    echo "directory no created";
}
?>
```

but it gave me back this error

```
[02-May-2021 09:19:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/u950517783/domains/mydomain.host/public_html/website/createdir.php on line 7
[02-May-2021 09:22:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/u950517783/domains/mydomain.host/public_html/website/createdir.php on line 7
[02-May-2021 09:22:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/u950517783/domains/mydomain.host/public_html/website/createdir.php on line 7
[02-May-2021 09:22:31 UTC] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/u950517783/domains/mydomain.host/public_html/website/createdir.php on line 7
[02-May-2021 09:22:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/u950517783/domains/mydomain.host/public_html/website/createdir.php on line 7
[02-May-2021 09:22:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/u950517783/domains/mydomain.host/public_html/website/createdir.php on line 7
[02-May-2021 09:22:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/u950517783/domains/mydomain.host/public_html/website/createdir.php on line 7
```

how can i fix that?
im using hostinger

Comment: Welcome. If you have questions how to do x or y on a specific hosting, you should contact their support and ask. We're glad to help out with issues with your code, but we're not a generic helpdesk for how to use off-site services.

Comment: my host support service said it's a problem with my code and told me to ask here

Comment: They are wrong. Permission error means that you need to change permission on the folder on the _server_. Your code can obviously not do that since it doesn't have permission to do that. It would be crazy if the code could give itself permission to a folder it doesn't have permission to and would defeat the whole purpose of having permissions in the first place. This is 100% a server configuration issue. You need to ask them how you can set write permission on that folder for PHP to write to it.

Comment: ok, i will, thanks a lot

Comment: Flawed approach. You can't/shouldn't create directories in the root / path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below

```
<?php
 session_start();

 $domain = $_SESSION['domain'];
 $mydomain = "/" . $domain;
 echo $_SESSION['domain'] . " " . $mydomain . "<br />";

 $old = umask(0);
 $mk = mkdir($mydomain, 0777, true);
 umask($old);

  if ($mk){
      echo "directory created";
  }else{          
      chmod($mydomain, 0777);
  }
 ?>
```

if `mkdir()` Not worked, You need to change permissions using `chmod()`

https://www.php.net/umask

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` for example to look at the value of `$mydomain` and then use this command to give the right access

```
chmod 777 -R <directory name>
```